# How to change the main grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

I have two ubuntu installs, A and B. The "A" is my main install. In B, I have compiled and installed a custom kernel. Then I run `sudo update-grub`.

The problem is that, running grub in "B", it does not affect the the actual boot screen shown on startup. Since that menu is populated if I run `sudo update-grub` in "A".

So the question is, how do I make grub of the fisrt ububtu installation to find the custom kernel which is installed in /boot of another installation of ubuntu

Comment: I suggest you try in the Ubuntu stack exchange site.

Comment: Sure. I put it here because I thought it was not Ubuntu specific. Anyway, should I just open a new question there or can I move it there?